# Laravel: Use github custom function non-laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In my Laravel Project, I want to use Github project having just 1 file.
No composer package included.
This file have some formulas to calculate the result and have 7 functions.

My Question:
Where to save this file in my project?

Or

Can I directly copy those functions in my controller/Model?

Please suggest.

Comment: Need more clarity what you mean by the question.

Comment: @Jigs1212
Updated with more details

Comment: @SVM why don't you just copy and past in a model ? or use a helper function(not recommend)

Comment: Thanks @SupunFictionPraneeth , I will copy and paste in model.
Just wanted to know the best practice.
whether to use in Model or Controller or Helper function.

Comment: @SVM using as helper is not recommended because it appear in everywhere in the app so there might be conflict with other functions

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I include code in laravel that is not part of a composer package I create a folder in the App folder with my nickname or companyname:

```
/project_folder/app/company/helperfunctions.php
```

You can still use composer to autoload the file if you want. Just include the classmap in your composer.json and add the path to your folder

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/company"
        ],

    },
```